# How can I separate sentences from a paragraph in Python when working with a database?

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working with a database that contains a column with paragraphs. Within these paragraphs, some sentences start with a #(hash symbol), some start with a * (star symbol), and so on. My objective is to create separate tables for sentences starting with #, * and other symbols.

To accomplish this task, I am using Jupyter Notebook and have successfully connected the database to my notebook, creating a dataframe. However, I am unsure about how to proceed with parsing the paragraphs to separate the sentences and create new tables in the database.

Could someone please guide me on how to parse the paragraphs? Should I consider using regular expressions for this task?[image]

Here is an example paragraph :

#1 The interrogative ending that sticks to the body language and indicates the meaning of asking in the place of "do it." *Even if we can't live, can we not live for a year or a thousand years?(They say we can't live a house, but will we not live a hundred years or a thousand years?) *How about you go to Batgale?(How are you going to plow the field tomorrow?) [Translator] #2 A question mark that sticks to the stem of "No" and means "Do it" in the place. *Isn't that Billewardy's spinning wheel (Isn't that horse wandering in the rock field?) [Translator]

I want to iterate through the paragraph and separate the sentences and make separate groups for the sentences that start with # and *.

#(hash symbol) group = **['The interrogative ending that sticks to the body language and indicates the meaning of asking in the place of "do it."' 

'A question mark that sticks to the stem of "No" and means "Do it" in the place.']**

*(star symbol) group = **[ 'Even if we can't live, can we not live for a year or a thousand years?(They say we can't live a house, but will we not live a hundred years or a thousand years?)'

'How about you go to Batgale?(How are you going to plow the field tomorrow?),' 

'Isn't that Billewardy's spinning wheel (Isn't that horse wandering in the rock field?)']**

Comment: Yes, you likely need a regex to `split` on your special characters. If you need help with specifics, please provide a reproducible example. You can try something like `re.split(r'\s*[#*]\d*\s*', your_string)`